# Can I extract child non-queryable object using bulk API 2.0?

Tags: bulk-api-v2

I want to extract whole ActivityHistory table that is non queryable and used as child for relationship with Account entity. How can I do it?

Here is an example, I want to extract 2 objects:

- Account
- ActivityHistory

I cannot directly extract ActivityHistory, because it's property queryable = false, trying to query this object results in the next api error:

> Object type 'ActivityHistories' is not supported

Accounts *describe* operation shows his childRelationships, and there is one with ActivityHistory named ActivityHistories. There is an example in documentation regarding accessing child relations with example query:

```
SELECT Id, Name, (SELECT Id, Status FROM ActivityHistories) from Account
```

But this approach also doesn't work with Bulk API because I am getting an error:

> Aggregate Relationships not supported in Bulk V2 Query with CSV content type

I was hoping to change content type, but Bulk API [supports](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_asynch.meta/api_asynch/query_create_job.htm) only CSV content type

Are there any ways to handle it?

Comment: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/27347/retrieve-activityhistory-via-bulk-api