# Can't I use ALL ROWS in asynchronous Salesforce queries?

Tags: bulk-api, asyncapexjob

I would like to perform asynchronous queries that could retrieve deleted rows as well. However, if I submit a batch with SOQL like `select Id, IsDeleted, Name from Account where IsDeleted = true and LastModifiedDate > 2016-01-01T00:00:00Z ALL ROWS` to an asynchronous job, the batch finishes with an error: `InvalidBatch : Failed to process query: MALFORMED_QUERY: ALL ROWS not allowed in this context`

Is there any way to perform this kind of query asynchronously? Or is it only available through the REST API?

Answer (score 5):

It sounds like there was a [discussion](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/34791/102) with someone in Salesforce that the Bulk API wasn't the right tool for monitoring deleted records.

There is always the Data Export functionality. It's kind of async, but unfortunately doesn't have an API.

Other than the REST API there is also the SOAP API, which is synchronous. See [queryAll()](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_calls_queryall.htm)